# Objective C - DropboxSDK: (401) Authentication failed -

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, dropbox

I'm using the dropbox SDK to save file to a user's dropbox account.
When the user taps 'save to dropbox' button for the first time, a popup window pops up and the user is required to login onto their dropbox account. I then upload a file to their dropbox account using `uploadFile` method provided by the SDK. However, the first time, it gives me the error:

```
DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files_put/dropbox/sampleFile.pdf - (401) Authentication failed
```

When I close the app and try again, it successfully uploads the file.

What may be causing the app to behave so strangely?

Comment: You're using the Core SDK, right? And could you please share your relevant code (e.g. the auth code)? I assume the sample app works for you? If so, it would be interesting to note any differences between your code and the sample.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it turned out that I initialized my DBRestClient from viewDidLoad like the Dropbox docs say, but since that happens before the dropbox account is linked the restClient is not properly set.

This can be easily fixed re-initializing your restClient or even better by using the following way to access your restClient.

```
-(DBRestClient*)restClient{
    if(_restClient == nil){
        _restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        [_restClient setDelegate:self];
    }
    return _restClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, use this code in your app hope this will help you.

```
if([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked])
        {
            //Do your drop box work here...
        }
        else
        {
            //If not linked then start linking here..
            [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
        }
```